# throw exception hangs up flow control

Tags: java, exception

Recently, I have been facing a problem with throwing exception in JDBC topic.

I synchronized Connection object by using 2 synchronized methods: getConnection() and releaseConnection(). Then another method which removes a row from database as follow:

```
public void removeItem(int itemID) throws ItemNotFound {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String query = "DELETE * FROM Student.Book WHERE id = ?";
    getConnection();
    try {
      ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
      ps.setInt(1, bookID);
      ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
      this.close(null, null, ps);  // method to close PreparedStatement and ResultSet
      releaseConnection();
      throw new BookNotFoundException("Book not found!");
    } finally {
      this.close(null, null, ps);
      releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Everything works well if no exception occurs. In case exception occurs, in catch block after releaseConnection() method, throw new BookNotFoundException("Book not found!") hangs up!! If i comment releaseConnection() method then it throws normally?

Comment: When putting code in a question or an answer, consider wrapping it with <pre> and <code>.  For example: <pre><code>I'm noob and that's not bad.</code></pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're releasing the connection twice.  The `finally` block will *always* run, even if a `catch` block runs.  My guess is it's doing the `throw`, then running the `finally` block, which tries to release the connection a second time.  I'm not sure how you implemented `releaseConnection()`, but if that blocks when the connection has already been released then this would explain the problem.

I think if you just remove the `close` and `releaseConnection` from the catch block it should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

`releaseConnection();` is both in your finally and your catch.  I don't think you want it in your catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You're releasing twice.  with the finally, it looks like this in the exception case:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(query);      
ps.setInt(1, bookID);      
ps.executeUpdate();
// catch
this.close(null, null, ps);
releaseConnection();     
// finally
this.close(null, null, ps);      
releaseConnection(); 
// exception flow
throw new BookNotFoundException("Book not found!");
```

which probably isn't what you want.

you could remove the close/release stuff in your catch and just leave the throw, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

when you throw the exception, the releaseConnection() method is called twice; once in the exception handler and once in the finally.

Try a variation of this:

```
 public void removeItem(int itemID) throws ItemNotFound
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String query = "DELETE * FROM Student.Book WHERE id = ?";
        getConnection();
        try
        {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1, bookID);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            this.close(null, null, ps); // method to close PreparedStatement and
                                                                    // ResultSet
            releaseConnection();
            throw new BookNotFoundException("Book not found!");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (isOpen())
            {
                this.close(null, null, ps);
                releaseConnection();
            }
        }
    }
```